# Crystal Report showing only first record in DetailReport Section VB.NET & SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

There are two tables in my database, `SalesInvoiceDetails` and `SalesInvoicesInventoryRowDetails`.

I have 6 x records in my table `SalesInvoicesInventoryRowDetails` from which Crystal Reports is showing only one (first record).

I checked by putting breakpoints. Dataset is filled with all data but its not appearing in Crystal Report except first record (only one line).

Please need kind help to solve the issue.

Thanks.

```
Dim row As DataRow = GridView1.GetDataRow(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle)

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    Dim objRpt As New XtraReport1
    Dim ds As New SalesInvoiceDataSet
    Dim adp1 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * From SalesInvoiceDetails Where InvoiceNo=N'" & row("InvoiceNo") & "'", DAL.OpenSqlConnection)
    adp1.Fill(ds, "SalesInvoiceDetails")

    Dim adp2 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * From SalesInvoicesInventoryRowDetails Where InvoiceNo=N'" & row("InvoiceNo") & "' order by Sno", DAL.OpenSqlConnection)
    adp2.Fill(ds, "SalesInvoicesInventoryRowDetails")

    DAL.CloseConnection()

    objRpt.DataSource = ds
    Dim s As New SalesInvoicePrintForm
    s.DocumentViewer1.DocumentSource = objRpt
    s.Show()
```

Comment: can you show me the crystal report? attach the images? and also cross check the Expressions as well.

Comment: Hi I tries to add picture and edit the post. But unable to attached. Can you please show me a way? Body is missing. This is the error after browsing the picture.